Swept wings: a subtle ambiguity?
In theory, a straight wing can be transformed to a swept wing, in two different ways:

A: by pivoting the straight wing about its root (analogous to an F-14 or F-111).
B: by shearing the straight wing, in a way that preserves the effective chord length.

According to most explanations, a swept wing design increases the critical Mach number of the wing, because the incident airflow experiences a reduced airfoil curvature. This is true in scenario A. As we can see from the diagram, after the wing is pivoted, the effective airfoil (pink) is longer than the original airfoil (black), and so it has a reduced curvature.
However, in scenario B, it seems that this explanation no longer holds. When a wing is sheared backwards, the effective airfoil is preserved.
My question is: does scenario B increase the critical Mach number compared to the straight wing, and if so, by what mechanism?


https://labs.engineering.asu.edu/aircraft-design/wp-content/uploads/sites/115/2023/03/AIAA2017-0266-KirkmanTakahashi-CriticalMachNumberPredictionOnSweptWings.pdf

@MichaelHall Purely a design sweep - apologies for the confusion.

@RobertDiGiovanni I can see how swept wing B has a lower critical Mach compared to swept wing A. However, I am wondering if swept wing B has a higher critical Mach compared to the straight wing. According to AeroAndy's PDF, the answers seems to be yes, because the sweep of the wing itself is important, in addition to the effective airfoil.

@natanijelvasic. Yes, the sweep definitely helps.  Originally wings were swept for balance purposes.  Later, it was discovered it helped increase the critical Mach number.  Amazingly, the thin wings, once though better at the then unheard of speed of 120 mph in the early 1900s, finally proved their worth in the trans sonic realm some 40 years later.

@MichaelHall "Shearing" is the proper term for the transformation that maps a rectangle to a parallelogram along one axis. You can look up "shear transformation". As it turns out, I found out today that my diagram is almost an exact copy from the book Introduction to Transonic Aerodynamics, and they use the same terms as I do: https://media.springernature.com/lw685/springer-static/image/chp%3A10.1007%2F978-94-017-9747-4_8/MediaObjects/187681_1_En_8_Fig6_HTML.gif

Yes, the sheared wing in scenario B increases the the critical Mach number as the sweep angle increases.
By what mechanism?
Short answer:
For a swept wing, the critical Mach number is defined as the free-stream Mach number at which we see a sonic velocity component, in the direction perpendicular to the wing's leading edge. As the sweep angle increases, this velocity component is initially scaled down by a factor of cos(Λ), and so a greater free-stream Mach is required for this component to become sonic as it accelerates over the wing.

Diagram from "Introduction to Transonic Aerodynamics" by Saeed Farokhi, Roelof Vos.
Long answer:
There are in fact two ambiguities to this problem. The first one is described in the question - pivot vs shear. The second one revolves around the definition of "critical Mach number".
Normally, the critical Mach number is defined as the free-stream Mach number at which we first see sonic flow over a body. If you imagine a vector field of velocities over the body, you are only interested in the magnitude of the velocity vectors.
In the analysis of swept wings, (and I will repeat myself) the critical Mach number is defined as the free-stream Mach number at which we see a sonic velocity component, in the direction perpendicular to the wing's leading edge. This is a rather different definition, because it allows for supersonic flow below the critical Mach number.
This second definition is used for the analysis of swept wings, because ultimately, we want the critical Mach number to correspond to a "critical regime" of flow, and not necessarily to the intrinsic properties of the flow. With swept wings, the critical regime is the point at which we form a normal shock over the wing, and a normal shock can only be formed if the flow component perpendicular to the leading edge is sonic/supersonic.
Therefore, we could say that it is almost "by definition" that sweeping a wing increases the critical Mach number. As the sweep angle increases, the perpendicular velocity component is initially scaled down by a factor of cos(Λ), and so a greater free-stream Mach is required for this component to become sonic as it accelerates over the wing.

Diagram from "Introduction to Transonic Aerodynamics" by Saeed Farokhi, Roelof Vos.
However, one could "force the point" out of pure curiosity, and ask: but does sweeping a wing increase the critical Mach number according to the standard definition of "critical Mach number"? In other words, does sweeping a wing delay the onset of supersonic flow altogether?
I think the answer is still "yes" for both scenarios A and B.
In scenario A, the effective airfoil (parallel to the free-steam flow) has a smaller thickness/chord ratio, so the flow is accelerated less, and the critical Mach increases (standard definition).
In scenario B, the critical Mach also increases slightly, but by a weaker effect. To quote from my previous attempt at an answer: Swept wing B has swept isobars, parallel to the leading edge. In other words, the pressure gradient will be perpendicular to the leading edge of the wing. An incident air particle will accelerate at an angle relative to its velocity, so its total speed will not increase as quickly compared to a straight wing (where the acceleration is aligned with the velocity). Therefore, a higher free-stream Mach is required to achieve sonic flow anywhere over the wing."

The resource you mentioned (Introduction to Transonic Aerodynamics, by Vos, R. and Farokhi,S.) defines the oblique wing and the sheared wing as in the image below:

For the oblique wing, you have the velocity decomposition due to the swept leading edge, meaning the velocity perpendicular to the leading edge will be $u_{oblique} = u_{\infty} \cdot \cos \Lambda$.
As the dependency between velocity and pressure is quadratic it leads to:
$$c_{l,oblique} = c_{l,\Lambda=0} \cos^2\Lambda \tag{8.7a}$$
For the sheared wing, you also have the velocity decomposition, as the  leading edge is swept. However, the flow going perpendicular to the leading edge is traversing an airfoil that has a shorter chord (compare the dotted airfoil with solid airfoil). This reduces its effective thickness $\frac{t}{c}$ and thereby the effective pressures and lift by a factor of $\cos \Lambda$. This leads to:
$$c_{l,sheared} = c_{l,\Lambda=0}\cos\Lambda \tag{8.10}$$
So for the oblique wing, the effect of sweeping is quadratic, whereas for the sheared wing it's not.
The effect on the lift will lead to a larger critical Mach number as explained here
To answer your question, both methods increase the critical Mach number but sweeping more than shearing.

In scenario B (shearing), by what mechanism does the coefficient of pressure drop as sweep angle increases? The airfoil sections parallel to the stream remain constant.

Do you have access to the book? It's explained there:
"For a swept wing the vorticity vector, γ is inclined at an angle π/2 − Λ. Therefore,
the two-dimensional lift vector, L, can be written as: $L'{\text{sheared}} = \rho{\infty} V_{\infty} \int_{0}^{c} \gamma(x) \cos{\Lambda} , dx$ "

@natanijelvasic, I was a bit confused by the different representations of sheared and oblique in your question and the book. I've now rewritten it in a way that seems more logical.

Yes, I think I agree with your answer. In the sheared case, we get cos^2 from the angled velocity, and a 1/cos from the shorter chord, and we arrive at cos for the 2D coefficient of lift. As for the total lift of the wing, the sheared wing is longer by 1/cos, so does that mean that we do not lose total lift in scenario B?

@natanijelvasic, the 1/cos does not come from the shorter chord, it comes from the shorter thickness/chord ratio. Because the airfoil get's stretched, it presents less curvature, and thus generates less lift. The total lift is just an integral of the airfoils, so either $c_{l,oblique} \cdot b$ or  $c_{l,sheared} \cdot b$

In the sheared case (B), if you define the airfoil as the section perpendicular to the LE (as the book does), then the airfoil's thickness/chord ratio is increased by a factor of 1/cos, right? It seems consistent with the maths. For the total lift of the sheared wing, we would then integrate this perpendicular airfoil across the wing length, which has increased in length by a factor of 1/cos. My conclusion is that the sheared wing generates the same lifting force as the straight wing.

@natanijelvasic, shearing a wing does not increase the total surface of a wing.

I agree, area is preserved. But its spanwise length is longer by a factor of 1/cos compared to the straight wing. If we consider the airfoil as defined in the book (perpendicular to LE), we would need to integrate it across the spanwise length, right?

When a plane encounters drag, the swept wing reduces surface area integration of airflow over the body. THus wing still generate lift but mitigate lots of air flow to stay stable and achieve high Mach. Changes in surface wing designs still permit sufficient airflows without compromising airs adherence to Grab adjacent parts of the wing surface. Cuts, notches, edges, furls and small grooves and ducts dot the wing surface of modern airplanes.
One best examples is F22

Which uses curves and slats and wing blending to pass air across much of it's surface but mitigates it's capacity to adhere and stick.

